# In which cases is SQL Statement object automatically closed?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

My question regards this statement :

> Releases this Statement object's database and JDBC resources immediately instead of waiting for this to happen when it is automatically closed.
>      http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close%28%29

So, in which cases is Statement object automatically closed?

Comment: Make sure you close any Statement (or ResultSet) **as soon** as you don't need it anymore. Don't rely on any implicit cleanup of those things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For JDBC 4.0 and earlier (Java 6 and earlier):

- A Statement is closed when the connection is closed

JDBC 4.1 (Java 7) adds the following:

- A statement is closed if `closeOnCompletion()` has been called and
  the `ResultSet` created from that statement has been read beyond the last row (and that read happened *after* enabling closeOnCompletion)

I don't consider *'try-with-resources'* to be automatically closing the connection, but 'just' syntactic sugar for  `try ... finally`.

Answer (score 2):

> You can use a try-with-resources statement to automatically close
>   java.sql.Connection, java.sql.Statement, and java.sql.ResultSet
>   objects, regardless of whether a SQLException or any other exception
>   has been thrown. A try-with-resources statement consists of a try
>   statement and one or more declared resources (which are separated by
>   semicolons). Source: [Using try-with-resources Statements to Automatically Close JDBC Resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/jdbc_41.html)

The following statement is a try-with-resources statement that declares one resource, stmt, which will be automatically closed then the try block terminates:

```
try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {

  // ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's closed when the connection that created it is closed.

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is regarding being sure about closing connections, resources and so on, i would simply use spring jdbc. It adds little overhead, it is pretty easy to implement and will make you get rid of those tedious try-catch-finally structures just for making simple queries.